# The fundamental nature of osmotic pressure: electromagnetic?

Tags: entropy, osmosis

As is known to all that osmotic pressure is an entropic force on a larger/statistical scale. But down to a smaller/microscopic sale, what's the origin or nature osmotic pressure? Is it electromagnetic as suggested by this answer below
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/33346

Comment: Unless you are talking about forces that hold atomic nuclei together, all forces are ultimately either gravitational or electromagnetic.

Comment: yes but can we explain 1 step further what force it really is and how it's associated with various objects in the scenario of a solution?

Comment: @mmesser314 Gases around ideality present a force when they're contained that's neither gravitational nor electromagnetic but entropic.

Comment: how should we categorize entropic forces